# Third party DFP ad not displaying on HTTPS page

Tags: google-dfp

Issue is that when i load https page it doesn't display ad and just display empty block and browser throws error saying 'Blocked loading mixed active content "http://adfarm.mediaplex.com/..."'. But same ad works fine on HTTP page.

What i feel is when google code loads on https page, it pulls in third party js for that ad and it has HTTP url which is trying to load on HTTPS page and browser blocks it.

Has anyone ran into this issue before. I need to fix it without changing URL in third party js ad code.

Here is how third party code looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/js/xxxxxxxxxx?mpt=%%CACHEBUSTER%%&mpvc="%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%>
</script>
<noscript>
  <a href="http://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nc/xxxxxxxxxx?mpt=%%CACHEBUSTER%%">
     <img src="http://adfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nb/xxxxxxxxxx?mpt=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
alt="Test Ad" border="0">
  </a>
</noscript>
```

Comment: You can not fix that on your end if the 3rd party code spits out `http://` URLs and provides no way of changing that.

Comment: Problem is that we only got code with http:// URL and we are trying to solve this issue on our end and trying to figure out solution which would avoid us going to our clients to look for code with https

Comment: You will _not_ be able to persuade just any browser into displaying insecure content on a secure page – this restriction is in place for a reason. You _could_ maybe try to iterate through the DOM elements the 3rd party script created within your page, look for all the URLs that the browser refused to retrieve because they use just `http://`, and replace them with their `https://` counterparts … but that would still require that access to the content via HTTPS is actually provided … and if that was the case, they could have given you a script that uses correct URLs in the first place …

Comment: I agree with you on browser security. But problem we have is code is provided by clients and its code that we ad into our DFP and then DFP outputs it on page where ad's need to show. I am not sure if client's will have https url for those third party javascript ad bocks. That is why i thought of asking this question here to see if someone has faced this problem before and how they handled it.

Comment: Again: There _is_ no way of handling that problem other than having your client provide resources that are accessible via HTTPS as well. If they don’t – well then no ads using their resources on HTTPS sites.

Comment: @johal : Help me out, What is the process to contact advertiser to get third party code?

Comment: No need for the `<noscript>` because google dfp won't work without scripts anyway. Basically this noscript tag (and stuff inside `<iframe>HERE</iframe>` tags) are kept in order to support Netscape 4. But in the past 10 years this has no meaning and should be removed to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Google DFP can be configured to serve ads over https.

http://doubleclickpublishers.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/introducing-next-generation-of-dfp-ad.html